# How do I customize the Emacs interface, specifically the tabs fonts in Windows?

Tags: emacs

How do I customize the Emacs interface, specifically the tabs fonts? I have included a screenshot of just how bad they look on Windows.

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but I think that should be something windows-specific.

Comment: You should always link to the library in question when you are asking about something which is not built into Emacs.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use another editor if you feel buffertabs is an essential feature for you.  Other editors implement this feature far better.  Tabs are useful when you primarily use the mouse with few buffers.  In Emacs, you primarily use the keyboard with a great many buffers.

Comment: @event_jr A bit of a snide answer. There's no One True Way of using Emacs. I've used it for 25 years, discovered Tabbars a couple of years ago, and have found that it's a very useful extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Tabbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode), you can customize the fonts by running `M-x customize-face` - you can then either hit Enter to customize all of them, or use tab-completion to select a single face.

The following faces are defined in tabbar.el:

- tabbar-button
- tabbar-button-highlight
- tabbar-default
- tabbar-highlight
- tabbar-selected
- tabbar-separator
- tabbar-unselected

Answer (score 2):

```
;; tabbar
(require 'tabbar)
(tabbar-mode)

;; example tabbar coloring code...
  (set-face-attribute
   'tabbar-default nil
   :background "gray60")
  (set-face-attribute
   'tabbar-unselected nil
   :background "gray85"
   :foreground "gray30"
   :box nil)
  (set-face-attribute
   'tabbar-selected nil
   :background "#f2f2f6"
   :foreground "black"
   :box nil)
  (set-face-attribute
   'tabbar-button nil
   :box '(:line-width 1 :color "gray72" :style released-button))
  (set-face-attribute
   'tabbar-separator nil
   :height 0.7)
```